# Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$. Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$ Show that $\exists c \in [0, 1]: f(c) = 3c^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$. Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$ Show that $\exists  c \in [0, 1]: f(c) = 3c^2$.
(Hint: consider $g(x) = f(x) − 3x^2$)

This is what I have so far. Let $g(x) = f(x) − 3x^2$.Then since $f$ is continuous and $3x^2$ is continuous, so is $g$. Hence it is Riemann integrable. Taking the Riemann integral at endpoints $[0,1]$, you get $\int_0^0 g = 0$ and $\int_0^1 g = 0$. Then $g$ is the constant $0$ or there exists a turning point in $g$ in the interval $[0,1]$. If constant, $0=c$. If $g$ is not constant, there is a turning point given by $G'(x) = 0$ where $G(x) = \int g$. Then $G'(x) = 0 \implies g(x) = 0 \implies f(x) − 3x^2 = 0 \implies f(x) = 3x^2$ and hence x=c.

I feel like I'm missing some justifications. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit, use Rolle's theorem on $G$, $G(0)=G(1)=0$ thus there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that $G'(c)=0$, and I think that naming the theorem you use is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the observation $\int_0^1 g(t) \, dt = 0$, you can immediately use the [integral variant of the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) to arrive at the desired conclusion (there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $g(c)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative  proof: $g$ is continuous  If it has  zeros then it  is always positive or always negative. Suppose $g(x) >0$ for all $x$. Then $\int_0^{1}f(x)dx>\int_0^{1} 3x^{2}dx=1$ a contradiction. Similar argument holds when $g(x) <0$ for all $x$.